# My checking account used to be joint- can I still use the checks with both names?

Tags: check, checking-account, joint-account

I have a checking account for bills that I mostly use a debit card for, but I need to pay something by check now. This account used to be a joint one with my mom when I was a kid, but we took her off the account a few years ago. I still have checkbooks of unused checks with both names - can I use them or are they void now?

Comment: Is the account number the same, and have you written checks previously on the account (when it was joint with your mom, or later)? That is, does your bank have a signature card for you?

Comment: I have used these checks before, yes, and the account number hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

Spoke to the bank, they said yes the checks are still useable. hope this helps someone else.